# Why the code in this simple C while loop is never executed?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

I didn't touch C for a while and now I am surprised that this while-loop is more mystic than I ever realized.

I tried `while ((byte_sent < sizeof(int)))` and `while (byte_sent < sizeof(int))`, the same result I got. The code inside the loop is never reached.

Tested with Gcc, Clion build chain, online compiler.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int byte_sent = -1;
    while ((byte_sent < sizeof(int))) {
        printf("We are in\n");
        break;  // Just want to know if the inner loop gets executed
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: byte_sent is signed while size_t is unsigned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try compiling with `-Weverything`(clang):

```
c.c:6:23: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'unsigned long' [-Wsign-compare]
    while ((byte_sent < sizeof(int))) {
            ~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
```

`sizeof` returns an size_t (Here a typedef for unsigned long), `byte_sent` is an int.

The integer is casted to size_t. So `byte_sent` is now 4294967295, as size_t(unsignd long) has no negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast sizeof(int) to an int: (int)sizeof(int), or it will automatically cast byet_sent to a size_t which is an unsigned long.

Edit: Look at JCWasmx86's answer for more detailed explanation!